# Does an open source login system which provides personal pages to the user exist?

Tags: authentication

He everyone, thank you for taking you time to have a look at my question.

Im relatively new to website programming, and was wondering if there are any open source login systems which provide the user the ability that when they log on they will have their own page containing their personal details.

The same concept as for example facebook or yahoo email, when the user enters credentials they are taken to their own space, not a generic members only section of the website.

Would appreciate any comment or suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but i hate unanswered questions. (Most frustrating)

I'm not much of a guru when it comes to this style of thing but there are many open source content management systems (CMS) applications out there that can handle this type of thing.

My personal preference would be [Drupal](https://drupal.org/), as i find it is quite intuitive, has quite a large support base and many features and plugins\modules that can handle user accounts, login redirects, shopping carts, etc.

I would also look at [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/) and [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) as they're also well supported open source CMS applications. All three of these CMS's have great tutorials that can be found by Googling or heading to Youtube.